# How can I accomodate a vanity with drawers when the drain is on right wall?

Tags: bathroom, drain, vanity, drawers

Is it possible to install a bathroom vanity with drawers between two walls where the drain is on the right wall? Here is the inside of the existing vanity:
[image: inside vanity]

The bottom of the drain is 12.5" from the bottom. Behind the back wall is a bedroom. The drain connects to the drain of the bathroom on the other side of the wall. The existing vanity is 30" high, and all the new ones are at least 34.5" high.

I can't find a vanity with drawers that sit under 12.5 from the ground. The nice vanities have drawers on both sides and the middle. Is it possible to adjust the drawers so that they could fit through the pipes?

Comment: Shorty drawers.

Comment: The drawer vanities I've seen have drawers that go all the way back.

Comment: Yes, so any drawers would need to be modified.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to install a bathroom vanity with drawers between two walls where the drain is on the right wall?

Yes.

The most simple way:

- Remove the drawers that interfere with the drain.

  - Optionally, replace them with a door for useful space.
  - Optionally, replace them with fake drawer fronts, making the space not useful.
  - Optionally, replace them with a door made out of the drawer fronts to make useful space that looks consistent with the rest of the cabinet.

More expensive and/or difficult methods:

- Buy a vanity with a door on the right instead of drawers.
- Buy a vanity with short drawers that don't go all the way to the back of the vanity.

  - Yes, this might be very difficult to find.
- Modify the drawers yourself to not interfere with the drain.

  - Shorten the drawer box by trimming the sides & bottom, then reattach the back.
  - With a couple of basic woodworking tools, this should be reasonably easy.
- Have a local cabinet shop modify or build new drawers for an existing vanity so that they'll work around the drain.
- Buy a custom vanity from a local cabinet shop with drawers explicitly designed to work around the drain.
- Rearrange the bathroom layout to put the vanity back on the wall where the drain is.
- Redo plumbing to move the drain to where the vanity's back wall is.

Comment: Since we're buying preassembled vanities from HD, replacing the drawer fronts with doors is not an option. From your second list, buying a vanity with drawers only on the left is best option, but that version is also more expensive.

Comment: If you can't buy a replacement door (from the manufacturer, most likely, not HD), you could build or have one built. Unfortunately, in your situation, you may well have to spend more on the vanity that fits your situation. I guarantee it'll be cheaper than paying to get the plumbing rerouted.

Comment: We want a vanity with drawers for aesthetic reasons, so it doesn't make sense to modify an existing drawer vanity to have drawers. A custom vanity sounds expensive.

Comment: What you _want_ and what _will work_ in your particular situation may not match up well at cheap, off-the-shelf HomeDepot prices. A custom vanity won't be cheap, but it might be less expensive than you image. Call some local cabinet shops and ask for quotes. Also, show them a picture of the vanity you want and ask what they'd charge to modify a couple of the drawers for you. Beyond that, nobody can help you simply because your situation is rather unusual.

Comment: There should be no reason you can't simply take the drawer fronts and modify them into a door.  Any halfway competent carpenter would be able to make that happen.

Comment: That was my last point on the "simple way" @Huesmann. Maybe it needed extra emphasis as that seemed to be lost on the OP.

Answer (score 1):

It is not likely that you could install a vanity with drawers on the right side.

I suppose you could tear into the walls and reroute the plumbing drains to come out of the wall at the back of the vanity. That may be more work than the result is worth.

To clear the drain, there would have to be extensive and very "crafty" modifications to at least some of the drawers. Again, maybe not worth it.

There are vanities that have an option to move the drawers to either left or right side.  Or, preassembled with drawers on the left.

Of course there is always the door only type.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately a vanity without drawers is what we'll have to go with.

Comment: You could reroute the drain but that will be a major undertaking.